# Mongo DB Atlas vs Azure cosmos DB Mongo API

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb, mongodb-atlas, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I would like to migrate my already existing Mongo DB to Azure Cosmos DB Mongo API, but could not figure out whether all the functionalities in use can be implemented in cosmos DB. Currently, I am using Mongo DB Atlas.
Following are some of the functionalities that we are using in Mongo Db atlas.

1. Grid FS
2. Master DB for connecting all the other DB's.
3. Indexing manually.
4. Profiler.
5. TTL for documents( Data gets deleted after 90 days from its entry date).
6. Vertical Scaling, ie., more than 500 databases with at least 3 to 4 collections in each database.
7. Storing certificates whose size is more than 2 MB.
8. All the files are in JSON format.

Can anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 1):

Most of these features are already supported and documented. You can refer to below links for more details:

[Azure Cosmos DB's API for MongoDB (3.6 version): supported features and syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb/feature-support-36) - This covers Gridfs, TTL

[Per-account limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/concepts-limits#per-account-limits) - This covers scaling limits of DB

[Manage indexing in Azure Cosmos DB's API for MongoDB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb/mongodb-indexing) - This covers Index creation

[Monitor and debug with insights in Azure Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/use-metrics)

I dont think there is master db in Azure Cosmos DB MongoDB API

Answer (score 0):

Note even though there are some things simillar, there are some major differences between MongoDB and CosmosDB for MongoDB API.

- **Explain outputs** - there is not shown detailed description of the winning plan, and instead only lists 'pathsIndexed' and 'pathsNotIndexed'
- **Index usage** - indexes that would be used in MongoDB might not be used in CosmosDB, that is true especially for compound indexes. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb/troubleshoot-query-performance).
- **Profiler** - one of the [unsupported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb/feature-support-42) features in 4.2
- **Transactions** - [multi-collection transactions, especially in sharded scenarios](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb/feature-support-42)

From the things you mention the version 4.2 supports **TTL** & **GridFS**
Regarding number of databases, the [500 is currently the maximum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/concepts-limits#per-account-limits) per account.

I hope this answered at least partially your question.